# Ruby style of accessing of elements of modules and classes

Tags: ruby

```
module Hints
    module Designer
        def self.message
            "Hello, World!"
        end
    end
end
```

is there any way to use the following code to access the message method?

```
p Hints.Designer.message
```

Instead of

```
p Hints::Designer.message
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The period `.` is only meant for accessing methods.

The double colon `::` is used to indicate namespaces.

Both modules and classes can be nested in each other. This creates a namespace for the nested class. (Technically, Module is an instance of Class.) Thus, the following is correct no matter if Hints or Designer are a class or a module.

```
Hints::Designer.message
```

You can try yourself by opening `irb` on the command line. `Hints.Designer.message` says `NoMethodError: undefined method 'Designer' for Hints:Module`.

**Update** *(as I am not allowed to comment...)*:

While many things in Ruby can be overwritten ("monkey patched"), basic operators cannot. `::` is a basic language feature that is and should not be customizable *(in order to prevent a big mess ;))*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot to access the `message` method, but you can't use it to access `Designer` module, because `Designer` it is not a method (but a constant). Dot is for invoking methods only.

Comment: just as we have namespaces in dotnet... they are accessed by dot notation... so what i want is to access them with the dot notation same as dotnet... can i..? any any any way..?

Comment: Not sure if I understand... You want to use C# syntax in Ruby? No can do.